# Neural network doesnt work when batch size is bigger than 1

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, gradient, gradient-descent

I am trying to create a neural network from scratch to learn from it. This is my first time working with neural networks. Right now i trying to train the network on logical gates. The input data looks something like this [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1] where the first four bits decide which operator to use and the two last bits is the operands p and q. The training data contains 64 examples.

If i do backpropagation after every single training example, the model solves the problem in a fraction of a second. But when i increase the batch size it cannot learn anything. The error gets stuck at around 0.25. It doesnt matter if i change topology, reinitialize weights, change learning rate etc, it always gets stuck around 0.25. I cannot understand why. Is there any fundemental error i have made in the training method that would cause this problem only when batch sizes are bigger then 1? (when batch size is 2 it also can solve the problem but very slow).

Also, i know that i can solve this problem more efficiently with numpy etc but this is just for educational purposes so I wanted it to be clear whats happening all the time.

```
def train(self, inputs, targets, epochs=1, batch_size=1):
    assert len(inputs[0]) == self.input_neurons
    assert len(targets[0]) == len(self.layers[-1].weights)

    gradient = [[0] * len(targets[0][0]) for i in range(len(targets[0]))]
    
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        error = 0
        training_data = list(zip(inputs, targets))
        random.shuffle(training_data)
        for index, (data, target) in enumerate(training_data, 1):
            result = self.feedforward(data)
            
            error += self.mean_squared_error(result, target)
            current_gradient = self.mean_squared_error_prime(result, target)
                
            for i in range(len(gradient)):
                for j in range(len(gradient[0])):
                    gradient[i][j] += current_gradient[i][j]
            
            if index % batch_size == 0:
                for i in range(len(gradient)):
                    for j in range(len(gradient[0])):
                        gradient[i][j] /= batch_size

                self.backward(gradient)
                gradient = [[0] * len(targets[0][0]) for i in range(len(targets[0]))]
                print(error / batch_size)
                error = 0


        left_over = index % batch_size
        if left_over != 0:
            for i in range(len(gradient)):
                for j in range(len(gradient[0])):
                    gradient[i][j] /= left_over

            self.backward(gradient)
            gradient = [[0] * len(targets[0][0]) for i in range(len(targets[0]))]
            print(error/left_over)
            error = 0
```